# Use NativeQuery multiple tables with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I've been searching for ages but haven't found any solution to my problem.
As I'm a real beginner I don't know much about EF, I tried so many solutions, but couldn't get the right path.

I'm working with EntityFramework6. 
I have 4 tables :

- Employee(EmployeeId,BadgeNumber,FirstName,LastName, ...)
- Shift(ShiftId, startDate, endDate, ShiftTypeId)
- TypeShift(TypeShiftId, description, startHour, endHour)
- Ticking(TickId, TickingDate)

I need to list all the Tickings within a period and dislpay also employee and the associated shift for the 'ticking date'. The relation between employee and shift is Many-To-Many Relationship. The bridge table generated in DB is 'EmployeeShift'

At first, I tried to do it with LINQ but I failed.
and I ended up with wirting a native SQL query (the query is tested and it's working) wich is :

```
 public List<Object> getTickings(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
 {
    try
    {

        var tickingList= model.Database
         .SqlQuery<Object>("select distinct Employees.numBadge,  Employees.EmployeeId, Employees.firstName, Employees.lastName, Tickings.TickingId, Tickings.tickingDate, TypeShifts.description, Shifts.startDate, Shifts.endDate, TypeShifts.startHour, TypeShifts.endHour
    from Tickings, Employees, Shifts, TypeShifts, EmployeeShift
    where Employees.EmployeeId= Tickings.EmployeeId
    and Tickings.TickingDate <= '" + toDate+ "'
    and Tickings.TickingDate >= '" + fromDate+ "'
    and Employees.EmployeeId= EmployeeShift.employees_EmployeeId
    and EmployeeShift.shifts_ShiftId = shifts_ShiftId
    and Tickings.TickingDate <= Shifts.endDate
     and Tickings.TickingDate >= Shifts.startDate").ToList<Object>();

       return tickingList;
 }
 catch
 {
    return null;
 }
}
```

Now I have multiple tables, so different objects. When added 'List' instead of 'List' the returned list is not null but I can't access the list. I'm sure that I'm missing something.
The question is : What should I do to make it work with native query ? or with LINQ

Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Best Regards.

Comment: Create a class `MyResult` with properties corresponding to columns in `SELECT Employees.numBadge,  Employees.EmployeeId, Employees.firstName, Employees.lastName, Tickings.TickingId, Tickings.tickingDate, TypeShifts.description, Shifts.startDate, Shifts.endDate, TypeShifts.startHour, TypeShifts.endHour
    from Tickings, Employees, Shifts, TypeShifts, EmployeeShift` Use this class `.SqlQuery<MyResult>` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, i would recommend to use SQL JOINS instead of the way you are getting records using the comma separated table names in your query. Any way, if it is giving you proper result then i don't mind it

Create an SQL View and then the Entity framework will generate the Class with the properties using the columns from that view. This way your query will be much simpler and you will be able to access it using clean & neat LINQ syntax instead of writing inline query

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vTickings]
AS

select distinct Employees.numBadge,  Employees.EmployeeId, Employees.firstName, Employees.lastName, Tickings.TickingId, Tickings.tickingDate, TypeShifts.description, Shifts.startDate, Shifts.endDate, TypeShifts.startHour, TypeShifts.endHour
    from Tickings, Employees, Shifts, TypeShifts, EmployeeShift
    where Employees.EmployeeId= Tickings.EmployeeId
    and Employees.EmployeeId= EmployeeShift.employees_EmployeeId
    and EmployeeShift.shifts_ShiftId = shifts_ShiftId
    and Tickings.TickingDate <= Shifts.endDate
     and Tickings.TickingDate >= Shifts.startDate

END
```

Now using simple LINQ to get the require records like

```
List<vTickings> tickings = db.vTickings.Where(vt=> vt.TickingDate<=toDate && vt.TickingDate >= fromDate).ToList();
```

I assume you have a variable called db that accesses the dbContext of entity framework.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try it and give a feedback

Comment: It worked perfectly, Thank you again. and I used sql joins, best practice :D